# Avoiding multiple calls when consuming a web service

Tags: java, web-services

I have a task where a user consumes XML from a third party. The XML feed is only updated once a day. The XML is stored in a database and returned to the user when requested. If the XML is not in the database, then it is retrieved from the third party, stored in the database and returned to the user. All subsequent requests will simply read the XML from the database.

Now my question. Say it takes 10 seconds for the request to the third party to return. In this period, there are multiple server calls for the same data. I don't want each of these to fire off requests to the third party and I don't want the user to receive nothing or an error. They should probably wait for the first request to complete at which point the XML would be available. This is a relatively simple problem but I want to know what the best way of catering for it is.

Do I just use a simple flag to control requests or maybe something like a semaphore? Are there better solutions based on the stack I intend to use which is the Play framework and a cassandra backend. Is there something I could do with callbacks or triggers?

By the way, I need to lazy load the data when the first request comes in. So, in this task it isn't an option to get the data in a separate process or when the app starts...

Thanks

Comment: Using a lock seems a pretty simple and nice solution. You could too "synchronized" the method that retrieves the data from the third-party and manage a simple boolean flag "isLoadingFromThirdParty".

Comment: Is it actually likely that you'll get multiple requests for the same data within the 10 second update window?, and what harm will it do? Will you slow down your processing significantly by making a subsequent call for the data? I ask because devs tend to over-engineer without clarifying the requirements. Somebody is paying for this and they may actually prefer to spend their money getting a basic working product that they can put in front of customers, before becoming overly worried about performance issues and efficiency.

Comment: @Engineer. I agree totally. This is more a technical task. If it were up to me I wouldn't even be lazy loading the data in the first place. The requirement is that there isn't a possibility of the third party endpoint being hammered if a large amount of users hit the site simultaneously - though I do agree that this is over-engineering

Comment: Ok, then the answer depends on your deployment architecture. It makes a big difference if you're running your application against multiple classloaders, be they in the same jvm (i.e. an application server), an enterprise environment (clusters and live-failover), or even deploying to a cloud. If you're inside a single classloader, then you can simply implement a singleton business-facade that either gets the information from the db or from the service within a synchronised method. If you're in a multi-classloader environment, then the problem is much, much harder to solve.

Comment: @EngineerDollery In a horizontally scaled application, assuming there's a single database, could you not just set up a transaction propagation level of nested - commit a state to the DB - "fetching data from remote DB". .

Comment: Yes, you can, but depending on your requirements you may have to ensure that nobody is using a dirty-read isolation level to see the old data while the new data is being written. The solution to the multi-classloader problem is to use an enterprise lock -- a single source of truth, and a single DB can perform that duty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a separate component that is responsible to get the `XML` from the third party and save it to the database.
In your code the various thread try to "fetch" the `XML` from this component.
This component returns the `XML` from the database if it exists. If it does not exist then you use a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) to synchronize.
So you do a [trylock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29) and only one of your threads succeeds. The rest will be blocked. When the lock is released the other threads are unblocked but the `XML` has already been fetched from the third party and stored to the database by the thread that first managed to gain the lock. So the other threads just return the `XML` from the DB.

Example code (this is just a "pseudo code" to get you started. You should handle exceptions etc but the main skeleton can be used. Do **NOT** forget to `unlock` in a `finally` so that your code does not block indefinitelly):

```
public String getXML() {  
  String xml = getXMLFromDatabase();  
  if(xml == null) {  
     if(glocalLock.tryLock()) {  
        try{  
            xml = getXMLFromThirdParty();  
            storeXMLToDatabase(xml);       
        }  
        finally {  
            globalLock.unlock(); //ok! got XML and stored in DB. Wake-up others!  
        }  
     }
    else {  
         try{ //Another thread got the lock and will do the query. Just wait on lock!     
             globalLock.lock();  
         }  
         finally {
             //woken up but the xml is already fetched  
             xml = getXMLFromDatabase();  
             globalLock.unlock();  
         }   
     }    
  return xml;  
}
```